# Are there any JSON:API parsers in PHP and JS?

Tags: javascript, php, parsing, json-api

I am considering using the JSON:API  (http://jsonapi.org) standard to output resources. But are there any parsers for this standard?

The JSON:API standard will put refereces for relationships in the relationships object in the json. The relationship data model it self will be given in the includes array. And it will put actual attribute values in the attributes object.

Are there opensource parsers PHP/JS which make this structure easy to use in objects. So I can get attributes like $book->title to get the title attribute and use $book->author to get the author relationship model.  Or in js with book.title and book.author.

Comment: On that very page you linked: http://jsonapi.org/implementations/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See here are lot of [implementations JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/implementations/#client-libraries-javascript) in different languages and frameworks. Choose which one need for your project.

Comment: Thanks Hamik, I missed this page entirely. Many Thanks!